# Why can type hints not be used in for loops?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Annotating the target in a `for` statement is not valid:

```py
>>> for i: str in test_string:
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    for i: str in test_string:
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I would like to know the reason for rejecting annotations at this point.

Comment: What do you want to do ?

Comment: because type checkers should be smart enough to know that `str.__iter__` returns `Iterator[str]`

Comment: for str(i) in test_string:

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The colon `:` historically has multiple meanings in Python. For example, it signifies the beginning of a block (`with a as b:`), slice subscription (`a[:]`) and dictionary pairs (`{a: b}`).

This makes it impossible or at least ambiguous to introduce `:` type hints at some positions. In specific, block headers such as `for` or `with` have a conflicting meaning of `:` signifying the end of the header. While an unambiguous syntax *could* be defined, this has the be weighted against *future* needs of maintaining and extending the syntax. So far, this has not been deemed worth it.

> #### [PEP 526 - Rejected/Postponed Proposals](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/#rejected-postponed-proposals)
>
> **Allow annotations in `with` and `for` statement:** This was rejected because in `for` it would make it hard to spot the actual iterable, and in `with` it would confuse the CPython's LL(1) parser.

---

For the time being, you can use a preceding type hint, or inline type comment:

```
a: str
for a in my_iterable:
    ...

for b in my_iterable:  # type: str
    ...
```

> #### [PEP 526 – Where annotations aren't allowed](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/#where-annotations-aren-t-allowed)
>
> Only single assignment targets and single right hand side values are allowed. In addition, one cannot annotate variables used in a for or with statement; they can be annotated ahead of time, in a similar manner to tuple unpacking:
> [...]

Answer (score 5):

You need to initiate it before the loop as per https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/#where-annotations-aren-t-allowed

so you can do like this

```
i : str
for i in test_string: 
    ......
    ......
```

Comment: In what sense does this initiate the variable? are there tangible effects to such a definition statement in python?